# How do I make new Date() and new Date("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss") create with the same timezone?

Tags: javascript, date

For some reason when I use both constructors each creates with a different timezone, they are both meant to be in the same timezone to then calculate the difference between each accurately.
[image: Image showing the timezone difference]

I tried parsing today's date and time manually but this seems like a bad workaround, I was wondering if there's another fix.
[image: Image showing bad fix]

Comment: The problem is that daylight savings has come in to effect between those 2 dates and dates are interpreted by default to be in the local timezone.

Comment: @phuzi is there a way to avoid that? the only other solution I can think of is to substract or add the time diff from the daylight saving if they exist

Comment: You could do that, but that would just change the time. The timezone would remain the same and the moment in time would now be wrong. Both dates accurately represent the moments in time you would expect.

Comment: We would ideally need to see the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Never mind, I have finally wrapped my head around it and the way it works makes sense. That hour that would be missing because of the daylight saving hasn't really happened so the time difference would be correct. Thanks for the insight

Comment: As a side note, you should be really careful about the format of date strings as it's likely that it will be misinterpreted at some point. Should `02-02-23` be 2nd Feb 2023 or 23rd Feb 2002 or even 23rd Feb 1902, etc. There are many ways to convert that string to a date.

Comment: Post code as text, not images.

Comment: Neither date has a timezone. The first string is parsed as local to the host, so whatever offset was in force at that particular date and time locally is used to create its time value (offset from ECMScript epoch), which does not have a timezone or offset. The second expression returns the current time value, which will be the same everywhere (for accurate system clocks) regardless of host regional settings or offsets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I am receiving dates with times in the format in the example and I want to display in a table a column that shows how long it's been since that time and date*

I don't think the problem you are trying to solve is an actual issue.

Lets work it out manually. Between 2nd February 2023 08:53:49 and 28th March 2023 11:31:59:

- 2nd February to 28 March - 2023-02-02T00:00:00 to 2023-03-28T00:00:00 is 54 days.
- 08:53:49 to 11:31:59 is 2 hours 38 minutes and 10 seconds.
- Take off one hour due to the transition to daylight savings gives 1 hour 38 minutes and 10 seconds.
- convert that lot to seconds gives 4,671,490 seconds.

Now lets see what JavaScript gives us

```js
const start = new Date('2023-02-02T08:53:49+0100'); // +0100 for Central European Standard Time
const end = new Date('2023-03-28T11:31:59+0200'); // +0200 for Central European Summer Time 

const seconds = (end - start) / 1000;

console.log(seconds);
```

And the result is identical.

Comment: Yep, I realised I was being stupid with the maths, thanks for the help!!